# The Morality of Rice

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, language

This is a classic riddle of mine. Please read the scenario below for the setup.

---

You are sitting around a campfire and a friend smiles and says:

> **Sam:** I have a riddle.

Intrigued, you ask him what it is. He points to the tent you are staying in that night, and asks:

> **Sam:** Is that tent Good Rice or Bad Rice?

Confused, you pick one at random and answer:

> **You:** Good rice?

He smiles and says you are correct. He then asks:

> **Sam:** What about that rock over there? Good Rice or Bad Rice?

You answer, slightly more confident this time:

> **You:** Good rice.

Grinning sheepishly, he replies:

> **Sam:** Nope, it's Bad Rice. Think about it! Now look, is that tree over there, is it Good Rice or Bad Rice?

Now thoroughly confused, you simply reply:

> **You:** I don't know... Tell me!

He replies with:

> **Sam:** Good Rice. That was easy! One more time.

He points towards the campfire and asks:

> **Sam:** Campfire. Good Rice or Bad Rice?

You are stumped, but guess:

> **You:** Bad rice?

He smiles and says:

> **Sam:** Excellent job!

---

Your objective is to discover what classifies things as "Good Rice" or "Bad Rice." Good Luck!

**Important for Editors: (slight spoiler)**

> Please do not edit formatting in the "scenario," as some grammar is important to the riddle.

Comment: Is this riddle Good Rice or Bad Rice? ;)

Comment: Excellent question! Good Rice!

Comment: Anything whose name starts with a "t" is good rice?  Fits the four questions asked.

Comment: Rock doesn't begin with T.

Comment: I'm agreeing with the names start with "t" (tent and tree are good rice, rock and campfire are bad rice).  Although the riddle being good rice doesn't fit from your comment.

Comment: I do know the answer to this riddle, I'll post the answer if no one gets it after a while. I will edit the question to be able to create more different objects and hopefully not be as broad.

Comment: The answer has been marked correctly.

Comment: I just realized that. I was on the edit page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> If "is" is in the question, it's good rice:

- Is that tent Good Rice or Bad Rice?
- Now look, is that tree over there, is it Good Rice or Bad Rice?
- Is this riddle Good Rice or Bad Rice? ;)

Otherwise, it's bad rice:

- What about that rock over there? Good Rice or Bad Rice?
- Campfire. Good Rice or Bad Rice?
- Also, what about this comment? Good Rice or Bad Rice? Bad Rice of course

Comment: Good job! You got it first, and your answer has been selected.

Answer (score 7):

Let's try again.
Good rice is determined by:

> When the question begins with *is* or something similar (though *is* is the only one used thus far).

Bad rice is when

> The question is simply phrased as "Good rice or bad rice?" with nothing coming before hand.

---

Old Answer

---

Anything that is good rice is

> Asked with a question beginning with a vowel. For example: "*Is* that tent good rice or bad rice?" and "*Is* that tree good rice or bad rice?"

While bad rice is

> Any question beginning with a consonant. "*What* about that rock over there?" and "*Campfire*. Good rice....".

Comment: Yet from this answer, could it possibly be both?

Comment: Not quite, but you're on the right track. Also, what about this comment? Good Rice or Bad Rice? Bad Rice of course.

Comment: Good job for the edit. Correct, but could you please spoiler it. I selected the other answer because it came first. Good work though.

Comment: @SamWeaver What do you mean spoiler it? I have the answer in spoilers currently.

Comment: Ah excellent, I must have missed it.

Answer (score 5):

I took it as something completely different. I realize it's not the intended answer, but it might be good to edit the question so this loophole is not possible.

Good Rice when

> The subject of the question (tent, rock, tree, campfire) has one or more occurrence of any letter. (tent, tree)

Bad Rice when

> The subject of the question (tent, rock, tree, campfire) has only 1 of each letter. (rock, campfire)

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't have set up the question like that. This is not the intended answer, but some variations of this riddle are based on that premise.

Comment: that even works for "riddle" but alas not for "comment" which was declared bad rice in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

It could be to do with the number of words in the sentence preceding "Good Rice or Bad Rice?" (since the OP asks people not to edit anything).

"**Is that tent** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Good Rice.
"**What about that rock over there?** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Bad Rice.
"**Now look, is that tree over there, is it** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Good Rice.
""**Campfire.** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Bad Rice.
"**Is this riddle** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Good Rice.
"**Also, what about this comment?** Good Rice or Bad Rice?" gives Bad Rice.

So 3 and 9 map to Good while 6, 1, and 5 map to Bad. So far, any function satisfying these simple criteria will work. Too broad?

Comment: Clever way to look at it.

Comment: What about: PHP Good Rice or Bad Rice... :o??

Comment: The answer to that question would be Bad Rice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm bit disappointed that the expected answer is bit unimaginative.

What if Sam intended to ask the question like this:

> "Is that tent Good Rice or Bad Ri**s**e?"

Similarly for all questions he meant

> Rise

instead of

> Rice

Then also the given answers make sense.

> Tent, Tree and fire are good 'rises' (as in high-rise building), but
>  stone is not a 'good rise'.