# I can’t figure this riddle out…

Tags: riddle

My friend said this riddle and I can’t solve it whatsoever.

It goes like:
**Rice Rice Rice. I’m going to make some rice. Good Rice Bad Rice. I’m going to make some rice**

Then we have to answer if the rice is good or bad. The words for when it is Good rice and when it’s Bad rice sound exactly the same to me and I can’t tell any difference in enunciation although I did get a hint saying that it was something to do with how it was said.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a game, where one person picks some characteristic that makes good rice, and others have to try to guess what that is.

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15586/the-morality-of-rice) contains a variant of the game (but that particular variant probably doesn't apply to your situation).

[This forum](https://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/forums/5513244/1) has another incarnation of the game, where the solution is

> hidden spoilertext in the post that can be seen by dragging the mouse over it to highlight it

The upshot is that the initiator of the game is the only one who knows what the difference between "good rice" and "bad rice" is.  It could have nothing to do with the words, but could have to do with whether their legs are crossed, or if they clear their throat before they say anything, or if they are touching something green when they ask the question.

The only way to figure it out is to keep guessing, and use the answers you are given to try to narrow down the problem space.